# sample_weight not recognised in XGBregressor

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to create an xgboost regression model in python using the scikit-learn API, specifying a weight column. Here is a minimal code example:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
model = XGBRegressor()
model.fit(df[['A','B']],df['D'],sample_weight=df['C'])
```

When I do, I get the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2d43e3c01bbb> in <module>()
      6 
      7 
----> 8 model.fit(df[['A','B']],df['D'],sample_weight=df['C'])

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'
```

As far as I can tell, the syntax is correct, according to the documentation:
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn

Others have reported this problem to the XGBoost developers some time ago, and it appears to have been fixed, so I'm not sure why this is still happening:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/1874

How can I install a version of xgboost that fixes this? I am working with Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda on Ubuntu 64-bit. Should I try doing this without Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by installing xgboost from github rather than installing it from pip. I have not yet got it to work with Anaconda, but the following did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo apt-get install git
git clone –recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; make -j4
cd python-package; python3 setup.py install
```